# Android: Uncheck the checkboxes on button click

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have a list with checkboxes, I have two buttons, save and clear. How to uncheck the checkboxes when I click the clear button,

```
public class myProfileActivity extends Activity {
    private List<Profile> contacts = null;
    private String TAG = "ContactListActivity";
    private String inputName;
    ListView lvContact;
    private Activity _activity;

    private ListView mainListView;
    private Profile[] itemss;
    private ArrayAdapter<Profile> listAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> checked = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static List<AttractionData> selectedData = new ArrayList<AttractionData>();
    private String profileType = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
        setContentView(R.layout.profilelist);
        _activity = this;

        profileType = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ProfileType");

        try {
            if (Constants.loadEntries != null) {
                Constants.loadEntries.cancel(true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Loading Data------", e);
        }
        Constants.loadEntries = new LoadEntries();
        Constants.loadEntries.execute();
        EditText editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtContName);

        editTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                inputName = s.toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "LoadMoreEntries --> Constants.loadEntries : "
                        + Constants.loadEntries);
                try {
                    if (Constants.loadEntries != null) {
                        Constants.loadEntries.cancel(true);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Loading Data--------", e);
                }
                Constants.loadEntries = new LoadEntries();
                Constants.loadEntries.execute();
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

            }
        });


        Button clearbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearbtn);
        clearbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


        }
        });



        Button savebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebtn);
        savebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (Constants.selectedContacts.size() > 0) {
                    ((CityPreferences) ProfileActivity.this.getApplication())
                            .storeAllContacts(Constants.selectedContacts);
                    Constants.selectedContacts= new ArrayList<Profile>();
                    finish();
                    v.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(v.getContext(), PalABActivity.class)
                                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));


                } 
            });


    }
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me

```
 Button clearbtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearbtn);
        clearbtn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
              for(int i=0;i < Constants.checkBoxState.length; i++)      
                 Constants.checkBoxState[i] = false;

              listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

In the onclick listener of the button

add

```
    chkBOX.setChecked(false);
```

Comment: Do for all checkboxes by inflating them all.

Comment: i have only one checkbox in my layout and tht is repeating for all views

Comment: You have to do individually for all views, or have a common place to return the status and set the status of the checkbox and try to update the status when you click button in that common place and set the checkbox state while the view is loaded from the present location.

Comment: i got the concept..but confused how to implement..any sample?

Comment: Yes I can provide give me few mins pls.

Answer (score 0):

Inflate (findViewById) the checkboxes you want to edit, and just call

```
myCheckbox.setChecked(false);
```

Comment: only first check box is getting cleared..?? i have one check box in the layout

Comment: You should do this for every checkbox which you want to adjust

Comment: i have only one checkbox in my layout and tht is repeating for all views

Comment: You should just split that up, CheckBox is already a separate View. No use in re-using the same one multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like this.

```
    public class MyApplication extends Application{

       private int check_state = 1;

        public void setState(int state)
           {
         check_state = state;
           }
        public int getState()
           {
          return check_state;
           }

      }
```

within your activity

Place where you want to set the checkbox state

```
        ((MyApplication)getApplication()).setState(0);
```

Place where you want to get the checkbox state

```
        ((MyApplication)getApplication()).getState();
```

in the manifest file

```
    <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:name=".MyApplication">
```

Comment: getting classcastexception...if you dnt mind can u integrated with my code in my question..Thanks

Comment: You must create a seperate class in seperate .java file , I suppose you have done with the same activity class. If you do as a seperate only then it will be available throughout the project. I hope you get my point.

Comment: i created separateclas..when iam callin in my activity it saying MyApplication cannot be resolced

Comment: Please post both your activity code and the new class you added, along with the logcat error as an edit to your question. Hard to spot the fault without the code.

Comment: getting classcastexception again on line ((MyApplication) getApplication()).setState(0);

Comment: MyApplication extends Application..i already have one class which extends Application...getting classcastexcetion on that class in log

Comment: Oh in that case just add the getState and setState code to that and the place where you call ((MyApplication)getApplication()) replace with the ((ClassthatextendsApplication)getApplication()).

Comment: i placed in my project application..but nothing happening..wen i click the clear butoon no action is performed???

Comment: setState just changes the value of the state and then you have to get the status of that checkbox using the getState button and set the chkbox.setChecked() with the value of the return value.

Comment: then do i need to use bot set and get states in my clear button code?

Comment: after checking..when i click clear button the checks should go...now where should i call set and get ?

Comment: yes I suggested this solution if you need the status of the checkbox for some other activities, if not just a line chkbox.setChecked(false) should do the job.

Comment: with chkbox.setChecked(false) only the first check box is working..remaing checks not disapearing ..i have only one checkbox in my layout file

Comment: I cant see any checkboxes in your code given in pastebin please paste the complete code relevant to the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22117/discussion-between-gridtestmail-and-teekib)